# Saving an array with core data Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to save an array within Core Data as a property. allImages is going to be assigned to a [String].  I've seen some people say to make it transformable. What is the proper solution to saving this into core data?
        [image]

Comment: I just answered, then deleted when I found that someone had already done a better job answering here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825604/how-to-save-array-to-coredata this example is storing an array of `Double`, but same approach applies for `String`.

Comment: Ya that helps a lot. I saw that and was wondering if anything had changed in swift 3. Also this may be a dumb question but now since NSObjects are managed by Xcode, how do I get reference to them so I can change the transformable to  [string]

Comment: Not a dumb question! Undeleted and edited by answer with a note about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> how do I get reference to them so I can change the transformable to `[String]`

This is actually a good point because the [answer I linked too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825604/how-to-save-array-to-coredata) assumed that you were creating your own NSManagedObject subclasses.

It's worth emphasizing that creating/maintaining your own NSManagedObject subclasses by yourself is a perfectly valid option, some might even suggest that it is a preferred option because you get better visibility of any changes overtime if your project is in a repository.

However - last couple of Core Data projects I have been using Xcode to create the subclasses which means you need create another property in an extension.

Here's the general approach that I've been using:

First, in your model file, I name the attribute with the type of object that it represents, in this case an array:

[image]

Then create an extension and add a computed property that casts between `NSArray` and Swift `Array` type:

```
extension CoreDataArrayObj {
    var images: [String] {
        get {
            return imagesArray as? Array<String> ?? []
        }
        set {
            imagesArray = newValue as NSArray
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting \n \ in between every different string the array. Does it have to do with converting from Array to NsArray, a core data thing, or something else?

Comment: No - the characters in the array shouldn't be transformed, so won't have `\n` or any other unexpected characters unless you're adding them somewhere!

Comment: In what file do you put the extension? I'm kind of confused on that part.