# Easiest way to store an array to Core Data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an array with values. How can I save this to Core Data in then easiest way? I know it has to do with ManagedObjectContexts and I already have Core Data added as a framework and set up the Entity. I tried following tutorial for this but I found it hard to generalize to my case.

Also, I have this:

```
var coordinates: [NSManagedObject] = []
```

but I want to save this:

```
var markersArray: Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D> = []
```

I believe that is not possible as that is not an NSManagedObject? How could I achieve that?

Comment: Use NSArchive to convert array into bytes , than save that bytes in core data. You Just need to have one variable . But this will cause you a tough work if you want to edit that array again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving an array with core data Swift 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726611/saving-an-array-with-core-data-swift-3)