# How can I store a specific format array in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am talking about this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The array I have is of type CLLocationCoordinate2D (google maps-type of coordinates).

Comment: You could use NSArchiver to encode your objects as binary data, but it would be better to create an entity with latitude and longitude floats and then have a one-to-many relationship to this entity type.

Comment: Thanks. A one-to-many relationship of what though? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save Array to CoreData?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825604/how-to-save-array-to-coredata)

Comment: Say your current entity is "Flight". Create a new entity "Location" with latitude and longitude attributes. Create an ordered one to many relationship from Flight to Location.