# 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release

Tags: swift, nsarchiving

I'm receiving a message in the log saying

> 'bundleNamePlaceholder'[8424:100146] [general]
> 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and
> will be removed in a future release

The message is not clear to me but I'm assuming that it might be something related to a CoreData object or maybe its content

Is there a way to catch what's throwing this message or what might cause it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

apple is removing `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData` at some point because it's not secure by default. if you're storing a transformable value using `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData` in coredata, it will then become unreadable.

https://www.kairadiagne.com/2020/01/13/nssecurecoding-and-transformable-properties-in-core-data.html

and https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/107533

Answer (score 47):

In my case the problem was in using `Transformable` type in CoreData for saving array of strings. By default CoreData uses `NSKeyedUnarchiver` instead of `NSSecureUnarchiveFromData` transformer. So changing the transformer solved this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

To find out what is causing these log messages, try adding symbolic break points for

`+[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:]`,

`+[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData:error:]`, and

`+[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:]`

This helped me finding the culprit.

Comment: In my case problem was because I forgotten to set data type and value transformer for transformable field in the xcdatamodel.

Comment: @couldDog , thanks, by "data type" do you mean the "Custom Class" field ???

Comment: @Fattie Yes, I mean the "Custom Class" field.

Comment: It helps in identifying the issue with Xcode 14.2

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is related to Core Data Transformable attributes however in my case this was also caused by an external library which was using `NSValueTransformer.valueTransformerNames` to iterate over all value transformer classes available in runtime. This was also causing the same errors in logs  and symbolic breakpoints given in other answer here did not catch them. So if you cannot find a reason why you have this logs you might also want to search for `NSValueTransformer` in your code and check if there isn't a similar problem somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was from GoogleAnalytics framework, thanks to @Lutz I could figure it out. For those facing issue from GA please use the updated sdk, this issue seem to be resolved
[GA SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution for saving UIColor to CoreData that worked for me:

1. Create class in new file:

   import Foundation
   import UIKit

class ColorTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer {
static let name = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: "ColorTransformer")

```
override static var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
    return [UIColor.self]
}

public static func register() {
    let transformer = ColorTransformer()
    ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
}

static func registerTransformer() {
    let transformer = ColorTransformer()
    ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
}
```

}

2. add to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate:

   ColorTransformer.register()
3. in .xcdatamodel > problematic atribute > Data Model Inspector > Transformer - "ColorTransformer"