# How to convert NSCoding to NSSecureCoding?

Tags: ios, swift, secure-coding

I got a message in log `'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release`. I am not sure how to convert this class to use NSSecureCoding. I am not sure which class is throwing this error. Could you please help me on how to convert this?

I am using `requiringSecureCoding: true`. Doesn't this make this secure?

```
class ZoneInfo: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var zoneID: CKRecordZone.ID
    var serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken? = nil
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case zoneID
        case serverChangeToken
    }
    
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(zoneID.encode(), forKey: CodingKeys.zoneID.rawValue)
        coder.encode(serverChangeToken?.encode(), forKey: CodingKeys.serverChangeToken.rawValue)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.zoneID = CKRecordZone.ID.decode(coder.decodeObject(forKey: CodingKeys.zoneID.rawValue) as! Data)!
        if let tokenData = coder.decodeObject(forKey: CodingKeys.serverChangeToken.rawValue) as? Data {
            self.serverChangeToken = CKServerChangeToken.decode(tokenData)
        }
    }
    
    init(zone: CKRecordZone, serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken? = nil) {
        self.zoneID = zone.zoneID
        self.serverChangeToken = serverChangeToken
    }
    
    init(zoneID: CKRecordZone.ID, serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken? = nil) {
        self.zoneID = zoneID
        self.serverChangeToken = serverChangeToken
    }

    static func decode(_ data: Data) -> ZoneInfo? {
        return try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ZoneInfo.self, from: data)
    }
    
    func encode() -> Data {
        return (try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: true)) ?? Data()
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ZoneInfo` class should conform to `NSSecureCoding`, not `NSCoding`.

Your `encode(with:)` is needlessly double-encoding the properties and your `init?(coder:)` is needlessly double-decoding the properties.

Here's a corrected version of your class:

```swift
class ZoneInfo: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    // Added to support NSSecureCoding
    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { return true }

    var zoneID: CKRecordZone.ID
    var serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken? = nil

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case zoneID
        case serverChangeToken
    }

    // Updated to avoid the double-encoding
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(zoneID, forKey: CodingKeys.zoneID.rawValue)
        coder.encode(serverChangeToken, forKey: CodingKeys.serverChangeToken.rawValue)
    }

    // Updated to avoid the double-decoding and to properly handle an invalid zoneID
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        if let zoneID = coder.decodeObject(of: CKRecordZone.ID.self, forKey: CodingKeys.zoneID.rawValue) {
            self.zoneID = zoneID
        } else {
            return nil
        }
        self.serverChangeToken = coder.decodeObject(of: CKServerChangeToken.self, forKey: CodingKeys.serverChangeToken.rawValue)
    }

    init(zone: CKRecordZone, serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken? = nil) {
        self.zoneID = zone.zoneID
        self.serverChangeToken = serverChangeToken
    }

    init(zoneID: CKRecordZone.ID, serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken? = nil) {
        self.zoneID = zoneID
        self.serverChangeToken = serverChangeToken
    }

    static func decode(_ data: Data) -> ZoneInfo? {
        return try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ZoneInfo.self, from: data)
    }

    func encode() -> Data {
        return (try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: true)) ?? Data()
    }
}
```

Since I can't test this with an actual instance of `CKServerChangeToken`, I was only able to verify that the above works with a zoneID. If you have an issue at runtime when you try to unarchive an instance of `ZoneInfo` with a real `CKServerChangeToken` value, let me know in a comment what the error is so I can update the answer if needed.

Note that the use of `CodingKeys` isn't normally used with `NSSecureCoding`. It's normally used for Swift `Codable`. Your use here does work, it's just a bit confusing.

I also suggest that your `encode` method return `Data?` instead of returning an empty `Data` instance on failure. Returning empty data will just lead to issues when you try to unarchive that empty data.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the double encoding, decoding issue and the use of NSSecureCoding. After I change to this code also I am getting this same warning. I don't have any class the has NSCoding anymore or NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData. Is there a way to know from where this error is coming? Thanks.

Comment: Figured. It's from the usage of Transformable type in Core Data.

Comment: If you are using Core Data (which isn't mentioned in your question), then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589985/nskeyedunarchivefromdata-should-not-be-used-to-for-un-archiving-and-will-be-re