# Core Data Array in swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, core-data

Hi guys I have a problem. After many videos i haven't understand how can I use the `Core Data` to store an array.

I have an application where in a view I putted 16 `TextLabel`. I need to use `Core Data` to Store a list of string. when I launch the program I need to load the data from the array. But sometimes I need to change the data of one `TextLabel` with a text from a text field, and then reload all the 16 text label.

Can someone help me with the code??

Sorry but I haven't understood How it works.

I have already create the project with core data.
thanks at all

Comment: We would like to help you with the code, but please share your code you already have with us so we can start somewhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546811/store-nsarray-in-core-data-sample-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suggestion: replace all your outlets with labels with `tag`s. This will produce less code which will be more readable. You can fill in your labels with convenient loops.

E.g., your "primary" labels could have tags 10-17,
your "secondary" labels could have tags 20-27.

To get a specific label just use

```
let label = view.viewWithTag(20) as! UILabel
```

Second, for storing an array of 16 strings, use `NSUserDefaults` which is much simpler and built for this kind of data volume and type.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(array, forKey: "myArray")
```

Answer (score -1):

there is my code. In this view I want to set all the 16 text label using an array. when I press the button under one of these text label i need to change the data whit a string from a granigliatoreTF and then reload all the 16 text labels. I have implemented only one button for start. Thanks to all

import UIKit
import CoreData

class DisposizioneGranigliatori: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource {

```
var disposizione = [NSManagedObject]()

@IBOutlet var granigliatoreTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var principale1LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var principale2LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var principale3LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var principale4LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var principale5LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var principale6LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var principale7LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var principale8LB: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var secondario1LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var secondario2LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var secondario3LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var secondario4LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var secondario5LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var secondario6LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var secondario7LB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var secondario8LB: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var modifiche: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

var pickerData : [[String]] = [[String]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    modifiche.hidden = true


    pickerData = [["12","161","164","165","176","177","245","246","247","250","255","256","262","263","266","267","268","269","270","271","274","275","278","287","289","290","293","301","303","306","307","308","328","330","336","337","340","344","346","347","352","355","357","374","377","381","383","387","391","394","395","399","400","401","403","417","421","423","430","F365","TGF 2666","FTS 2061"],["00","0,09","0,10","0,12","0,12-00","1400","Z","0,14-0,12","0,14","0,16","0,18","0,21","0,25","0,31","0,40","0,52","0,71"]]

    self.picker.delegate = self
    self.picker.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// The number of columns of data
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

// The number of rows of data
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData[component].count
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[component][row]
}

}


@IBAction func bigbagPrinc1(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func bigbagSec1(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

}

Comment: You should include this in your question. Use the "edit" link below the question.